# Can select individual columns but not select *

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite DB that have a corrupted table somehow. I can't access the table in my sqlite gui tool but when I query the same table with just a single column, I get the value fine.

So this do NOT work(SQL Error: SQL logic error or missing database):

```
select * from table
```

This DOES work:

```
select column from table
```

Result back from this query is the value of column. Perfectly normal result.

Any suggestions how this can happen? Any suggestion for any analysis tool for the actual file?

`Seems that one of the columns were corrupt and prevented the select * to fully work. But the question remains, what can possibly be written to this column that prevents a select?`

Comment: "So this do NOT work:" - how does "NOT work" show? Unexpected results? An error message? An exception?

Comment: Good point, I have updated the question.